# does iOS Safari support storageEvents?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, local-storage, mobile-safari

I have the following sample code (hosted at https://d-dsuo5j1fc.now.sh/) which should show 2 constantly changing date strings. The first is in a simple 500ms loop, the second is the result of a StorageEvent. The idea is that this page is loaded in two tabs such that each tab is alerted to a localstorage change in the other tab.

It works fine in Chrome/iOS, but in Safari iOS, the second string is never updated, suggesting that it didn't fire the onStorage event.

```
<body>
    Own timer<span id='s'> </span><br>
    From storage event <span id='ev'> </span>
</body>
<script>
let s = document.getElementById('s');
let ev = document.getElementById('ev');
function onStorageEvent(storageEvent){
    ev.innerHTML = storageEvent.newValue;  // display the storage event value
}
window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageEvent, false);
// every 500ms, generate a new string, display it and write it to localstorage
setInterval(()=>{
    let d =  new Date().toGMTString() + ' ' + Math.random();
    s.innerHTML = d;    // display our fresh value
    localStorage.setItem('foo',d);  // and write it to localstorage
}
,500);
</script>
```

Also, any suggestions for a good resource for the HTML5 incompatibilities of Safari on iOS?

Comment: did you try something like `alert(StorageEvent)` on Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Were you testing in private browsing mode?** In that case Safari behaves differently due to Apple's privacy concerns.

Here's a video showing the storage event working fine on iOS 6 on iPhone 5 (same code just changed to support ES5, `let` converted to `var`, arrow function converted to normal function). But as soon as you turn on private browsing it stops working.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wo0kqHXrc_0

Comment: That's weird... I couldn't get it working from iOS 10.3 downwards (iOS 10.3 included).

Comment: Oh and it does indeed not work. Your string is not updating as it should. It should update every second or so.

Comment: @Aaron3219 It doesn't update every second because it's a mobile device and both tabs don't work at the same time. Back then two apps were barely working at the same time.

Comment: Mmh... so it could **theoretically** work. However, theoretically does mean in theory and not in practice. So in my definition it doesn't ;) agreed?

Comment: @Aaron3219 It is working. The second tab gets the event.

Comment: Yes it gets the event, but not every second. Which makes sense if only one tab is working. Try it out with [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dfv28wrj/4/show) link. If it updates how it should, then we should see the appended text every second.

Comment: @Aaron3219 We don't see updates every second because the other tab gets suspended, your desktop browser of choice even does that.

Comment: That is not true. Browsers have the ability to run tabs in the background. Nowadays even Safari is capable of it, as you can see in my answer. However, it is true that Browsers normally assign lower priority execution order to inactive tabs.

Comment: @Aaron3219 You didn't understand me. I never meant that browsers weren't running tabs in the background. I meant that browsers suspend tabs (when you haven't used the tab in a while or your device is in need of resources). Chrome on the desktop does that since 2015: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding

Comment: Ah, then we mean the same thing. I just called it lower priority execution order. However, I didn't know that browsers are actually fully suspending unused tabs.

Comment: You nailed it. I had inadvertently opened in a private tab.

Answer (score 1):

> It works fine in Chrome/iOS, but in Safari iOS, the second string is never updated, suggesting that it didn't fire the onStorage event.

I tried it as well with the following code:

```js
let s = document.getElementById('s');
let ev = document.getElementById('ev');

function onStorageEvent(storageEvent) {
  ev.innerHTML = storageEvent.newValue; // display the storage event value
  document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br>something has changed (Event type: '" + event.type + "')";
}
window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageEvent, false);
// every 500ms, generate a new string, display it and write it to localstorage
setInterval(() => {
  let d = new Date().toGMTString() + ' ' + Math.random();
  s.innerHTML = d; // display our fresh value
  localStorage.setItem('foo', d); // and write it to localstorage
}, 500);
```

```html
Own timer<span id='s'> </span><br> From storage event <span id='ev'> </span>
<div id="console"></div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dfv28wrj/4/show) link because this example will not work in the SO sandbox tool. So I displayed the `event.type` (`document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br>something has changed (Event type: '" + event.type + "')";`) in the string to be sure that the right event has been fired. But as you can see in the GIF below it works just fine for me. I also did some other tests to double check and all of them worked fine.

I am using iOS 12.4.

[image: GIF]

---

> Also, any suggestions for a good resource for the HTML5 incompatibilities of Safari on iOS?

To triple check I also searched for some credible sources. The most known are **[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/)** (no search results) and **[developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event)** but even they have no info about it.

[image]

So the triple check won't work. However, since I already tried it out myself with different iOS versions (8, 9, 10, 11) it obviously does have the support, and we can answer the question:

> does iOS Safari support storageEvents?

With a **yes, it does support storageEvents from iOS 11 and upwards**.
Let me know if you have any questions.

---

### Edit #1

By the way, if you want to test it out yourself (if you don't own an iPhone like I do) there are some emulators out there such as [appetize.io](https://appetize.io/demo?device=iphone6s&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=11.4).